# How to filter an array by multiple (all) of some object's values?

Tags: javascript

In the below code, I am trying to reduce the `persons` array only to persons which match perfectly with `filters` object.

Currently the output is an array of objects that have a match in ANY of the object keys. How can I adjust it to return only the second person - the one that has a perfect match with ALL filters?

```js
var persons = [
 {city: 'London', 'age': 18, 'name': 'Josh'},
 {city: 'London', 'age':42, 'name': 'Josh'},
 {city: 'New York', 'age': 42, 'name': 'Mike'},
 {city: 'Tokyo', 'age': 33, 'name': 'Kazuna'},
]

var filters = {
 city: 'London',
 age: 42,
 name: 'Josh',
}

function filter(person){
 for (let key of Object.keys(filters)) {
  if (person[key] == filters[key]) {
   return person
  }
 }
}

var filtered = persons.filter((person) => filter(person))
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: You want to use every()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the function `every` to accomplish that.

```js
var persons = [{     city: 'London',     'age': 18,     'name': 'Josh'   },   {     city: 'London',     'age': 42,     'name': 'Josh'   },   {     city: 'New York',     'age': 42,     'name': 'Mike'   },   {     city: 'Tokyo',     'age': 33,     'name': 'Kazuna'   }, ],
    filters = {city: 'London',age: 42,name: 'Josh'};

function myOwnFilter(person) {
  return Object.keys(filters).every(key => filters[key] === person[key]);
}

var filtered = persons.filter(myOwnFilter);
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the entries of the filters object and check every person with every entry of it with 
[`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which returns `true` if *every* predicate is `true`.

```js
var persons = [{ city: 'London', 'age': 18, 'name': 'Josh' }, { city: 'London', 'age':42, 'name': 'Josh' }, { city: 'New York', 'age': 42, 'name': 'Mike' }, { city: 'Tokyo', 'age': 33, 'name': 'Kazuna' }],
    filters = { city: 'London', age: 42, name: 'Josh' },
    filterEntries = Object.entries(filters),
    result = persons.filter(person => filterEntries.every(([k, v]) => person[k] === v));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

use every() to make sure everything matches

```js
var persons = [
 {city: 'London', 'age': 18, 'name': 'Josh'},
 {city: 'London', 'age':42, 'name': 'Josh'},
 {city: 'New York', 'age': 42, 'name': 'Mike'},
 {city: 'Tokyo', 'age': 33, 'name': 'Kazuna'},
]

var filters = {
 city: 'London',
 age: 42,
 name: 'Josh',
}

const result = persons
  .filter(person => 
    Object.keys(filters)
      .every(key => 
        filters[key] === person[key]
      )
  )

console.log(result)
```

You can improve performance moving the Object.keys() out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&&` to create the condition in the `filter`

```js
var persons = [{
    city: 'London',
    'age': 18,
    'name': 'Josh'
  },
  {
    city: 'London',
    'age': 42,
    'name': 'Josh'
  },
  {
    city: 'New York',
    'age': 42,
    'name': 'Mike'
  },
  {
    city: 'Tokyo',
    'age': 33,
    'name': 'Kazuna'
  },
]

var filters = {
  city: 'London',
  age: 42,
  name: 'Josh',
}


var filtered = persons.filter(function(person) {
  return person.city === filters.city && person.age === filters.age && person.name === filters.name

})
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var persons = [
    {city: 'London', 'age': 18, 'name': 'Josh'},
    {city: 'London', 'age':42, 'name': 'Josh'},
    {city: 'New York', 'age': 42, 'name': 'Mike'},
    {city: 'Tokyo', 'age': 33, 'name': 'Kazuna'},
]

var filters = {
    city: 'London',
    age: 42,
    name: 'Josh',
}

function filter(person){
    for (let key of Object.keys(filters)) {
        if (person[key] !== filters[key]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}



var filtered = persons.filter((person) => filter(person))
console.log(filtered)
```